# Mysql HOUR() converts -HH to HH, is this a feature or a bug?

Tags: mysql, time

If I do a query such as the following:

```
SELECT HOUR( TIMEDIFF('2012-08-12 02:25:00', 
                      '2012-09-14 02:25:33') ) as result
```

the result is 792, even though I'm subtracting a past data from a future date.

If I remove `HOUR()` and do:

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF('2012-08-12 02:25:00', 
                '2012-09-14 02:25:33')  as result
```

Then the value is `-792:00:33`. Therefore clearly `HOUR()` is converting -792 to 792. I've tried it with other dates and result is the same (always positive hour being returned).

[The manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_hour) doesn't say anything about this behaviour.

Is this a bug, or is it a feature that I can rely on to be present on all recent mysql installations?

Comment: The second statement throws an error for me: *Bad format for Time '-792:00:33'* See: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6eb12/2

Comment: Actually it behaves exactly like the first sentence in the spec (in the link you posted): `Returns the hour for time.` - it omits the seconds the way it should be!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name its working on my end, is that site running mysql ?

Comment: @ClickUpvote it doesn't work - it returns: `java.sql.SQLException: Bad format for Time '-792:00:33' in column 1: SELECT TIMEDIFF('2012-08-12 02:25:00', '2012-09-14 02:25:33') as result`

Comment: @alfasin Of course, omitting the mins and seconds is expected, but it also converts a negative hour value to positive, e.g `-792` to `792` in my example

Comment: @alfasin Is that site using MySQL? Its working on my end

Comment: on mysql 5.5.27 it behaves exactly as for Click Upvote question

Comment: reading the manual again, it behaves as specified. return value range is 0-23 for daytime values, or > 23 for larger times.

Comment: My bad - I thought that the problem you're having is with the seconds - I missed the positive/negative part...

Comment: The SQLFiddler errors is a problem (bug?) with the MySQL JDBC driver. I get the same error locally when using a Java/JDBC based query tool.

Comment: @guido That doesn't say anything about what's the expected behavior for hours < 0? Hence I wasn't sure if this a feature or bug

Comment: @Click Upvote I think it's an expected feature. Think the time value as an individual entity with an optional sign (as a whole, not for single component of time); HOUR() just *extracts* the hour value from the time, with no calculations. Think similarly for coherence at the MINUTE() and SECOND() functions: you cannot have a time in the format 273:-20:23, while for -273:20:23 it would always return 20, not -20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it's an expected behaviour (can't say if bug or feature).
See the example:

```
mysql> select hour('-23:00:00');
+-------------------+
| hour('-23:00:00') |
+-------------------+
|                23 |
+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.04 sec)
```

If you need to get the hour from there I'd recommend parsing the result (if possible, outside SQL)

Answer (score 7):

There's a way to get the positive hour and the negative hour. `EXTRACT` will get the negative one.

```
SELECT EXTRACT(HOUR FROM '-01:00:00'), HOUR('-01:00:00')
```

Will return:

```
-1    1
```